# Every PID is UFD, question about proof

Tags: abstract-algebra

In my book I am reading a proof for the statement in the title. It starts of with saying: "let $R$ be a PID and let $a \in R$ be a nonzero and nonunit element. We wish to show, to begin with, that $a$ is divisible by an irreducible element. If $a$ is irreducible then we are done. Otherwise $a=a_1b_1$ , where $a_1$ and $b_1$ are non units"

I dont get this, why can we write $a$ as a product of two nonunits only because it is not irreducible, it doesnt state anywhere in the definition of irreducible element that we can do this, all we know about $a$ (since it is a non unit) is that IF it is irreducible and IF it can be written as a product of two element then they must be non units. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: **Hint** _ The negation of: *every* factorization of $\,a\,$ is trivial, is: *some* factorization of $\,a\,$ is nontrivial, i.e. $\,a = bc\, $ for nonunits $\,b,c.\ \ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look again at the definition, thinking carefully about the negation of an implication: an element $ a \in R$ is irreducible if $a$ is not a unit and $a = xy \implies $ $x$ or $y$ is a unit. The negation of this statement is that $a$ is not irreducible if there exist $x,y$ non-units such that $a = xy$.

(Remember that the negation of $A \implies B$ is $B \cap \neg A$. If it were the case that the only way to write $a = xy$ was with one of $x$ or $y$ a unit (certainly $ a = a \cdot 1$ is one way), then $a$ would be irreducible.)

Comment: I am having troubles understanding this. Correct me where I am wrong: let $a$ be a nonunit, then $a$ is irreducible if whenever $a=xy$ \implies $x$ or $y$ is a unit. This statement only tells us that IF $a$ can be written as a product of two element THEN either one must be a unit, if this is not true, that is the element is not irreducible then it means that IF $a=xy$ then we may very well have $x$ and $y$ nonunits. I just dont see the existence of such a product, what am I missing, can you explain again please?

Comment: The issue you are having is not about the definition of irreducibility but in negating an implication. You are correct: if $a$ is a non-unit, then $a$ is irreducible if $a = xy \implies$ $x$ or $y$ is a unit. Now the negation of that is that there exist $x$, $y$ non-units such that $a = xy$. Let's see why: if instead there do not exist $x$, $y$ non-units such that $a = xy$, then $\forall x,y$ such that $a = xy$, $x$ or $y$ is a unit, which is precisely the definition of irreducibility. So for an element $a$ to be not irreducible, there MUST exist non-units $x, y$ such $a = xy$.

Comment: To sum it up, the negation of $P \implies Q$ is $P \cap \neg Q$. If it is still unclear, please let me know.