# Why is F[x] a UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

When reading the proof for if $R$ is a UFD, then $R[x]$ is a UFD, the author uses a fact that $F[x]$ is a UFD. I don't quite understand this.

> Why $F[x]$ is a UFD? ($F$ is the fraction *field* of $R$).

Can someone explain to me why? Thanks.

Comment: What about $F$? I suppose it is the fraction field of $R$. In this case is easy to see that $F[x]$ is an euclidean domain (the degree function is the same as in the case of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$) and ence an UFD...

Comment: @JosephCurwen yup, it is the fraction field of R, i don't get how setting the degree function the same as q[x] will prove this fact? and why Q[x] comes in, when i have no Q[x] in my question?

Comment: it is even PID.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218261/prove-that-any-polynomial-in-fx-can-be-written-in-a-unique-manner-as-a-product

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Ahahaha the quickest duplicate ever!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the book *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms* by *Cox D., Little J., O'Shea D.* you can see :

[image]

Note that every PID is UFD.

Comment: there is a hint [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849361/every-pid-is-ufd-question-about-proof) for "every PID is UFD"

Comment: and id you search on the internet "every PID is UFD" you will see complete proofs

Comment: While it is true that every PID is a UFD, and that $k[x]$, because it is a Euclidean domain (has a Euclidean division, as is used in this proof), is a PID, it is actually (slightly) _harder_ to prove that every PID is a UFD than that it is to show that [every Euclidean domain is a UFD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Properties). Notably the fact that it is an [atomic domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_domain) (has factorizations in the first place) is easier/more effective for the case of Euclidean domains. So this is not really helpful for (just) the current question.

Answer (score 0):

We want to define a degree function for $F[X]$ and deduce that $F[X]$ is an euclidean domain and so an UFD.

Hou to construct our function?

Look at $\mathbb{Q}[x]$:

The *constant terms* have *degree zero* and the *polynomials with leading monomial $x^n$* have *degree $n$*.

Let's set now the same values of degree function for $\mathbb{F}[x]$.

We have to prove:

- If $a$ and $b$ are in $\mathbb{F}[x]$ and $b$ is nonzero, then there are $q$ and $r$ in $\mathbb{F}[x]$ such that $a = bq + r$ and either $r = 0$ or $deg(r) < deg(b)$.
- For all nonzero $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{F}[x]$, we have $deg(a) \leq deg(ab)$

but now the proofs of these facts are the same as the case $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: I think the assumption that OP is acquainted with the fact (and proof) that $\Bbb Q[x]$ is a UFD is highly questionable. After all, as you say, it is basically the same thing (a special case that is not in any way different from the general case). On the other hand maybe OP is acquainted with that fact, and maybe with a proof, that $\Bbb Z$ is a UFD.